# Hardy-Littlewood maximal function $f^*$ is greater than $f$ for measurable $f$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable function on $\mathbb R$, and $\forall x\in \mathbb R$, define the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function $f^*(x)=\sup_{t>0}$$1\over{2t}$$\int_{x-t}^{x+t} |f|$

My question is how to show $|f(x)|\le f^*(x)$ for almost every $x$?

For the case $f$ is integrable, this can be proved using Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem. But I do not know how to extend this argument to general measurable functions.

Comment: if $f$ is not integrable, then $f^*$ is infinite

Comment: @mathworker21 I don't think it's quite that simple. For example  if $f(t)=1/(1+|t|^{1/2})$ then $f$ is not integrable but it seem to me that $f^*$ is finite almost everywhere. What's true is that if $f$ is not integrable in some neighborhood of $x$ then $f^*(x)$ is infinite.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich yea, I thought that's what he meant by integrable. It's very well known that you just need $f$ locally integrable for Lebesgue's differentiation theorem

Comment: What if you apply the (locally) integrable-case result to $f_n(x):=f(x)\cdot 1_{\{|f|\le n\}}$, and then let $n\to\infty$?

Comment: The desired inequality holds at all points $x$ where $f^*(x) = \infty$. Otherwise, if $f^*(x) < \infty$, then $f$ is integrable in the neighbourhood of $x$, and hence in that neighborhood you can apply Lebesgue's differentiation theorem.

Comment: @Hayk It seems that if $f^*(x)<\infty$ for some $x$, then $f$ is integrable on all sets of the form $(x-t,x+t)$. Then for all compact subset of $\mathbb R$, it is contained in some $(x-t,x+t)$, so $f$ is locally integrable, Does this sound right?

Comment: @RunningMeatball, technically, if you allow $t$ in the definition of the $\sup$ to be anything larger than $0$ (assuming $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$) then yes, you get $f$  is locally integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ if there exists $x\in \mathbb{R}$ with $f^*(x) < \infty$. Otherwise, if you restrict $t>0$ to say $0<t \leq 1$, then still you might be able to cover all compact subsets of the domain of $f$, but still the inequality you need will hold true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1: $f^*(x) = \infty$ $\forall x$. The inequality holds.

Case 2: $f^*(x) < \infty$ for some $ x$.

We have $\frac{1}{2t}\int_{x-t}^{x+t} |f|<\infty$ and thus $\int_{x-t}^{x+t} |f|<\infty$ $\forall t>0$. For any compact $K \subset \mathbb R$, there exists $t$ such that $K\subset (x-t,x+t)$, hence $$\int_K |f| \le\int_{x-t}^{x+t} |f|<\infty$$This shows $f$ is locally integrable. By Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem, $$|f(x)|=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{2t}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}|f|\le\sup_{t>0}\frac{1}{2t}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}|f|=f^*(x)$$ for almost every $x\in \mathbb R$.